# Airflow SSHOperator: Set Charset Encoding?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, character-encoding, airflow

When using the [Airflow SSHOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator/index.html) to run a command on another machine, some of the words appear as `\uXXXX` (eg. `\u7ec8\`) in the Airflow logs which I believe is in UTF-16 encoding.

Is it possible to set the charset encoding so that these characters will be displayed correctly in the Airflow log files?

```
remote_run = SSHOperator(
    task_id='remote_run',
    ssh_conn_id='win10machine',
    command='C:\\Python38\\python.exe C:\\Users\\hello\\foobar.py',
    dag=dag)
```

*Airflow worker is running inside a Docker container based on an linux image. Airflow v1.10.10 is being used on a Ubuntu host.*

---

**Log Snippet**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

...

Exception: \u63a5\u53e3
```

Putting this into a [unicode converter](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter) as a UTF-16 string shows the expected unicode characters output.

Comment: Are theses words produced by the foobar.py. Can you post the actual log snippet?

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov Yes these are produced by foobar.py. Updated question with the log snippet, and a link to the unicode converter that properly converts this UTF-16 string to the desired output.

Comment: I would probably try to change the script to produce correct encoding (UTF-8, ASCII?), rather than trying to change the encoding of the logs.